# Connecting to pushtopic event via Java Client via Proxy

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, java, streaming-api

I am trying to run the emp connector sample provided by Salesforce. When i tried running the sample, i was getting socket timeout. After investigating, i realized that our company is behind firewall and any traffic going outside needs to be routed via proxy.

I looked at the SFDC documentation and there was no information on how to add the proxy to the java client. After skimming through some jetty documentation, i was able to find it. I am able to connect to my SFDC org via Emp client but when it tries to connect to https://*.salesforce.com/cometd/43.0, i get a connection timeout.

When i run the same code without proxy (at my home desktop), everything looks great. So it looks like either the code is not yet supporting the proxy or i am setting the proxy wrong. Can someone help ?

LoginHelper.java

```
    public static BayeuxParameters login(URL loginEndpoint, String username, String password,
        BayeuxParameters parameters) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(parameters.sslContextFactory());
    URI proxyURI = new URI("https://PROXY_HOST:PROXY_PORT");
    try {
        AuthenticationStore auth = client.getAuthenticationStore();
        client.getProxyConfiguration().getProxies().add(new HttpProxy("PROXY_HOST", PROXY_PORT));
        auth.addAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication(proxyURI, "ProxyRealm", "PROXY_USER", "PROXY_PASSWORD"));
        //client.getProxyConfiguration().getProxies().addAll(parameters.proxies());
        client.start();
        URL endpoint = new URL(loginEndpoint, getSoapUri());
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues/833

Comment: i figured out the problem. I forgot to add the proxy in one more class. That did solve my issue and everything is working great

Comment: Cool. Please write and accept your own answer (preferably with a code sample) to help other folks who might be reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did is added the proxy configuration in 2 JAVA files :
1) EmpConnector.java

```
  public EmpConnector(BayeuxParameters parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
    httpClient = new HttpClient(parameters.sslContextFactory());
    ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = httpClient.getProxyConfiguration();
    List<ProxyConfiguration.Proxy> proxies = proxyConfig.getProxies();
    HttpProxy pro = new HttpProxy("YOUR_PROXY_HOST", PROXY_PORT);
    proxies.add(pro);
    //httpClient.getProxyConfiguration().getProxies().addAll(parameters.proxies());
}
```

LoginHelper.java (login function)

```
client.start();
        ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = client.getProxyConfiguration();
        List<ProxyConfiguration.Proxy> proxies = proxyConfig.getProxies();
        HttpProxy pro = new HttpProxy("YOUR_PROXT_HOST", PROXY_PORT);
        proxies.add(pro);
        URL endpoint = new URL(loginEndpoint, getSoapUri());
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.